# Linker error, using g++ to link to a library compiled by gcc, undefined reference to that function

Tags: c++, c, gcc, linker

I wrote a C function which calls a function defined in `openssl/sha.h`, let's say the declaration is `"helper.h"` and implementation is `"helper.c`". Then I compiled that function using gcc and put it in a library:

```
gcc -std=c99 -lcrypto -lssl -c helper.c -o helper.o
ar -rc helper.a helper.o
```

Then I wrote a cpp function that calls the function declared in `"helper.h"`. I added

```
extern "C" {
#include "helper.h"
}
```

stuff in that cpp file and then I used

```
g++ test.cpp helper.a -o cpp
```

Then the ld error occurs and says I encounter undefined reference for a function defined in `openssl/sha.h`. I wonder how to resolve that?

Comment: add `-lssl` to second gcc command as well.

Comment: Note that the `-l` options of the first command are ignored since no linking is done.

Comment: @riodoro1 I tried and it doesn't work

Comment: @Quentin yes and I used `nm` to checked the `helper.a`, seems the functions defined in `sha.h` are labeled U. Do you know how to solve that?

Comment: @shihanlin9 That's pretty normal, sice helper.a uses them but they are defined in libssl. Please define "doesn't work", because adding `-lssl` to your final link command is what should be done.

Comment: @Quentin My problem is in the final link stage when I use g++ to compile `test.cpp` and link to `helper.a` and libssl, it seems the functions in libssl were not defined, e.g. `g++ test.cpp helper.a -lcrypto -lssl -o cpp`, after adding `-lcrypto -lssl`, it still says the functions defined in `openssl/sha.h` are undefined reference.

Comment: @shihanlin9 Update your question with this new info, and copy/paste the exact output the compiler shows you.

Comment: @nos Sorry I'm off campus currently and it's weird that my pc cannot connect to this website but my tablet can... so I type each character on tablet and I will revive this later when get back to campus. Luckily I already got the answer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `ssl` and `crypto` libs to your final command in order to link these libs to your program.

You must also respect the order: since `sll` is using `crypto` so you must put `ssl` first and `crypto` after.

```
g++ test.cpp helper.a -o cpp -lssl -lcrypto
```

Comment: That works! It seems to be a matter of order that I should put `-lcrypto -lssl` after `helper.a`. What should keep in mind when linking to static libraries like `-lpthread` and so on? I don't have much experience handling static libraries and all I have done before is just linking some object files :-)